# For iid random variables, what is the limiting form of $E\left(\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^mX_i-\mu\right)^3$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value

Suppose $X_1, \ldots, X_m$ are i.i.d. with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. Suppose we have that $E\left(X_m^4\right)<\infty$, I am wondering what the limit of

$$
m^2E\left(\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^mX_i-\mu\right)^3
$$

tends to. How can I deal with

$$
E\left(\sum_{i=1}^mX_i\right)^3\,\,?
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean $\mathbb E\left[ (\ldots)^3\right]$ rather than $\left(\mathbb E[\ldots]\right)^3$ which would be trivial.

Let $Y_i = X_i - \mu$, so $Y_i$ are iid with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma^2$, and you're looking for

$$ \frac{1}{m} \mathbb E \left(\sum_{i=1}^m Y_i \right)^3 = \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^m \sum_{k=1}^m \mathbb E[Y_i Y_j Y_k]$$
There are $m(m-1)(m-2)$ terms where $i,j,k$ are distinct, and these terms are each $\mu^3$.
There are $m$ terms where $i=j=k$, and these terms are each $\mathbb E[Y_i^3]$.  We don't know what this is, but it's finite.  The other $3 m (m-1)$ terms have two of $i,j,k$ equal and the other different, and these are each $\sigma^2 \mu$.  So you're asking for

$$ \lim_{m \to \infty} \left((m-1)(m-2) \mu^3 + \mathbb E[Y_i^3] + 3 (m-1) \sigma^2 \mu \right)$$

If $\mu \ne 0$ the limit is $\pm \infty$, depending on whether $\mu$ is positive or negative.  If $\mu = 0$ the limit is $\mathbb E[Y_i^3]$.

Answer (score 1):

By SLLN $\frac  1 m \sum\limits_{i=1}^{m} X_i \to \mu$ a.s. By Jensen's inequality applied to the convex function $x^{4}$ we see that $E(\frac  1 m \sum\limits_{i=1}^{m} X_i)^{4} \leq E(\frac  1 m \sum\limits_{i=1}^{m} X_i^{4})=EX_1^{4} $ so $(\frac  1 m \sum\limits_{i=1}^{m} X_i )^{3}$ is uniformly integrable. This implies that the required limit is $0$.

Comment: May I ask how the 4th power inequality implies the 3rd power expression is uniformly integrable? Thanks.

Comment: It is a well known fact that if $E|Y_i|^{1+\epsilon}$ is bounded then $(Y_i)$ is uniformly integrable. Ref: K L Chung's book. @user321627

Comment: Why is there a discrepancy between your answer and Robert Israel's answer?